# Facebook and different URLs for each sharer, could this affect the amount it is shared

Tags: seo, facebook, query-string, sharing, canonical-url

On my quiz site, I have been allowing people to share the quizzes with their friends using the Facebook sharer popup.

At first I just let them share the quiz on it's own, but I decided it would be nice to have a query string that passes data so that the previous person's result would be visible to the sharer, like this: http://example.com/oJXp7r?t=5QMCCQ

Now, I want to give the content the best visibility possible on Facebook.  I have a canonical URL set up in the header for each quiz, which I was hoping would allow Facebook to realised the preferred URL.

I wanted to know if adding the query string to each sharer should affect the sharability or visibility of the content on Facebook.

I know, for instance, that if more than one of your friends shares the same link, it will come up prominently and say '3 of your friends shared X content'.... if I have the query string will it stop this kind of thing from happening or will it realise it's the same URL?

Answer (score 1):

Using the default Facebook sharer, it would see URL's with different query parameters as completely separate URL's so subsequently, not detecting that 3 other Facebook user's have shared the same content. You'd have to come up with a workaround to this.

Comment: Is this true, even if the content has a canonical URL specified?

Comment: Yes. It's still a different URL being shared.

Comment: I wonder if this would be affecting my share rate then, just because it's different urls

Comment: You could write a custom widget in PHP that catches the URL minus the query parameters and then uses Facebook's API to see which of their friends has shared that URL instead.

Comment: What I'm really concerned about is that having everyone share a different URL (a different query string) is affecting the amount the people that see the post on Facebook.  I introduced the query strings to the share buttons on my website on the 25th March and my hits have been declining ever since... I removed the query string code last night so that I could see what happens to see if the hits go back up again.  Either it was the query strings hampering the virility on Facebook, or the content has just come to it's natural end... any thoughts?

Comment: The only people that would see the shared quizzes would be friends of those that shared it on Facebook. Whether the same URL or different ones, this wouldn't change - the visibility of the shared content would only be dependant on this. You can create a FB app though that does way more like auto posts to the user's wall etc - you'll need to look at further development to get the most out of this.

Comment: Indeed, I have looked at integration using the API to post actions and custom posts.  All of the sharing worked perfectly before I made this change, content was being shared rapidly.   Specifically the '3 of your friends posted the url X' probably doesn't work anymore with each URL being unique...

Comment: I guess I should be able to answer this question in a few days time.  If things get better now that I have removed the query strings I will report back :)